# Linux Device Driver - How to receive notification of added device when exporting GPIO?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver

This is my first post to stackoverflow and hopefully this question is appropriate.

I am writing a Linux device driver for a virtual GPIO chip configured with some pins for input and output where some are aliases for physical pins and others are virtual. For the virtual pins, I have a user space application that intends to provide the other half of the virtualization through back doors to the chip device and the exported pins. For example, the chip configures GPIO 224 as an interruptible input, with the intent of blocking a call from user-space such as `cat /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip224/Virtual Input/value`. To do this, my approach is to add a special file attribute to "Virtual Input" named "virtual" (for example). The call to "cat" will invoke the "gpio_chip.get" callback and wait on a queue. My user-space application will later decide when the value changes, and write the updated value to ".../Virtual Input/virtual", which internally updates the value and unblocks the wait.

The problem I am having is adding the device attribute to the exported pin. From the command line the pin is exported using `echo "224" > /sys/class/gpio/export`, which in turn calls my "gpio_chip.request" callback. This is the only place I find to potentially add the attribute in a synchronous fashion. However, looking at the GPIO class driver I see a call occurs to the "request" callback, followed by a call to "gpio_export" which then calls "device_add", adding the device (i.e., the pin) to the system. In other words, the device does not yet exist in the context of the request handler and I cannot add the attribute.

I noticed there seems to be no bus associated with the exported pin device (nor the chip) and was trying to create my own so as to receive a notification via the `gpio_export` call to `device_add` but have not had any luck.

Any ideas to point me in the right direction are appreciated.